# Use SwiftData @Query to create an array of unique values for a column in a model

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here's my model:

```
import SwiftData

@Model
class Topic {
    var category: String
    var hobby: String
    
    init(category: String, hobby: String) {
        self.category = category
        self.hobby = hobby
    }
}
```

In a view, I want to use @Query to create a list of the unique values in category.

Like this:

```
@Query var categories: [\Topic.category]
```

Of course, this does not work. But seems to me that the syntax ought to be something like that line of code. From the model, create an array of the data in a given column. I'd want to add a part to this to make the values unique.

Comment: Swift data doesn’t seem to have that capability right now

Comment: Core Data doesn't support it either so don't hold your breath :). Of course, you could get the result through a computed property.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comments, here is a simple approach:

```
@Query var topics: [Topic]

var uniqueCategories: [String] {
    topics.map { $0.category }.uniqueValues()
}

...

List {
    ForEach(uniqueCategories, id: \.self) { category in
        Text(category).bold()
        ForEach(topics.filter({ $0.category == category }) {
            Text(topic.hobby)
        }
    }
}

...


// unique values from an array
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    
    func uniqueValues() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var seen: Set<Iterator.Element> = []
        return filter { seen.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```